# MySQL- How to use a date index

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a table where each row is time-stamped on a `date` column and another table with dates and indexes.

The table has two columns: `date` and `index`.

I get syntax error every time I try:

```
select index from date_index where 'any where condition'
```

I get no error with:

```
select * from date_index
```

I get syntax error with:

```
select date,index from date_index
```

Why?

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to escape MySQL [reserved words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html) used as identifiers:

```
SELECT date, `index` FROM date_index
```